# Hibernate, how to use Interceptor along with getCurrentSession()?

Tags: hibernate

I can only find `Interceptor` used with `sessionFactory.openSession`:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = ...;
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(new MyInterceptor()); // it works! (MyInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor)
```

Is any way to use `Interceptor` along with `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add it to the `Configuration` object, for example,

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {

        URL r1 = HibernateUtil.class.getResource("/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        Configuration c = new Configuration().configure(r1);
        c.setInterceptor(new AlmadrabaInterceptor());
        ...
```

Take a look also to the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-interceptors),

> A Session-scoped interceptor is specified when a session is opened.

```
Session session = sf.withOptions( new AuditInterceptor()).openSession();
```

> A SessionFactory-scoped interceptor is registered
>   with the Configuration object prior to building the SessionFactory.
>   Unless a session is opened explicitly specifying the interceptor to
>   use, the supplied interceptor will be applied to all sessions opened
>   from that SessionFactory. SessionFactory-scoped interceptors must be
>   thread safe. Ensure that you do not store session-specific states,
>   since multiple sessions will use this interceptor potentially
>   concurrently.

```
new Configuration().setInterceptor( new AuditInterceptor() );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it is really helpful! And I also find another simple to use SessionFactory-scoped interceptor: `sessionFactory.setEntityInterceptor(new MyInterceptor());`

Comment: And do you know is it possible to add multiple interceptors?

Comment: Well, not sure what exactly you want to do, but you could make your interceptor a sort of aggregator of interceptors. You know what I mean?

Answer (score 2):

```
Session session = sf.withOptions( new AuditInterceptor()).openSession();
```

This throws a compile time exception that `withoptions` is not applicable for the argument. Session scoped interceptor like shown above

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(new MyInterceptor());
```

is also throws a compile time exception. As overloaded opensession method was available in Hibernate 3 but not in hibernate 4.

At session level use below syntax:

```
Session session = factory.openSession();
session.sessionWithOptions().interceptor(new CustomInterceptor());
```

Answer (score 2):

In latest hibernate 5, only

```
try (Session session = sessionFactory.withOptions().interceptor(interceptor)
.openSession()){
//the code
}
```

something like this works.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to use interceptor along with `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession`, we can set a SessionFactory-scoped interceptor:

`sessionFactory.setEntityInterceptor(new MyInterceptor());`

Then every session can use this interceptor.

Answer (score -1):

In case you are using spring managed transactions with Hibernate and wish to use session-scoped like interceptors with `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`, this article (https://leakfromjavaheap.blogspot.com/2013/07/contextual-session-local-hibernate.html) has more details. Note that the other answers here make use of sessionfactory-scoped interceptors so if that is what you are looking for do refer to those.

Some example code using spring managed transactions is below.

Service Layer Code :

```
@Transactional()
public List<Language> getLanguageList() {
    return lookupDao.getLanguageList();
  // the auditInterceptor will be called before the transaction completes..
}
```

DAO Layer Code :

```
public List<Language> getLanguageList() {
    List<Language> resultList = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery(..)
            .getResultList();

    return resultList;
}
```

The spring transaction configuration would look like this :

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {
    ...
    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() throws IOException, NamingException {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
        txManager.setEntityInterceptorBeanName("auditInterceptor"); // that's the trick
        return txManager; 
    }
}

    @Component
    @Scope("prototype") // and that's the trick
    public class AuditInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {...}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thank you for the comment but I do not appreciate your down voting the answer ! I have added more details from the article itself so that this can be helpful to others even if the article link changes. Using Spring managed transactions with Hibernate is quite commonplace these days and this answer will be helpful to folks looking to utilize per session interceptors with sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().

Comment: I did not downvote this answer. Please don't just blindly assume such things; I was just trying to help you.

Comment: My bad, apologies for the same. Guess I am now referring to whoever down-voted the answer without leaving any feedback ! Thank you again for your comments, it did help me edit and improve the answer !

Comment: why `@Scope("prototype")`?

Comment: every time a spring managed transaction is started, the Hibernate transaction manager will use the spring BeanFactory to fetch the entity interceptor bean by name. Since the interceptor is marked as prototype, a brand new interceptor bean is created by the BeanFactory. The only purpose to mark it prototype is every transaction will have it's own instance of the entity interceptor without having to worry about sharing the interceptor instance state with other running transactions. If the entity interceptor code is thread-safe and stateless, then we need not mark it as prototype.